# Links to a given item?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

For any particular question or answer posted to math.stackexchange.com, is there a quick way to tell which other questions or answers link to it? ${{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}$

Comment: This seems similar to your older question: [what links here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662/what-links-here)

Answer (score 3):

What about the "Linked" section on top the "Related" section?
[image]

Comment: For a more glorious example, consider [this rather popular question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199), which has a pile of "Linked" questions associated with it.

Comment: I see a "Related" section on a question I just looked at, but no "Linked" section.  I looked.  Does that appear only when at least one link exists?  If so, I'd consider that a bug.

Comment: @Michael, could you mention the question that is supposed to be linked to another question, but doesn't have a "Linked" section? Usually, it takes a while to show up, especially if the link was only made a few minutes ago...

Comment: I don't know of any that is supposed to be linked to another question, but doesn't have a "Linked" section.  Rather, I know of a particular question in which I found no "Linked" section.  My suspicion, then, is that that is visible only when such a link actually exists.  _That_ is what I would consider a bug, if indeed it happens.

Comment: This problem is that it doesn't inform people.  If one is wondering if some other answers or questions link to a particular answer or question, and if it happens that none do, then one does not get informed of the existence of such a thing as a "Linked" section, so one doesn't know that _if_ any such links exist, then one would see such a section.  Conseequently one does not find out that no such links exist.

Comment: Contrast this with what happens in Wikipedia articles: If one clicks on "What links here" under the "Tool" menu, one get a page that either lists the article that link to the one in question, or explicitly states that there are none.

Answer (score 2):

There is also search functionality, for example you can enter into search something like
[url:http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q*/1363/](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmeta.math.stackexchange.com%2Fq%2a%2F1363%2F).

AFAIK there are two differences to the automatically generated list of linked questions:

- Search ignores links to comments.
- Only questions linking **to** the given post are shown.

This type of search is used when you click on *see more linked questions*; this link is available on frequently linked questions where the *linked* section would otherwise be too large.

Comment: This implies that "more linked question" is not necessarily a superset of "Linked questions". So confusing... As a test, I am [linking to a comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/how-to-link-to-a-comment#comment6254_1818) from a comment, to see if the system catches this.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You can see this behavior if you click on *more linked questions* for example in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages). Relevant posts at meta.SO:
[“See more linked questions” only works one way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176302/see-more-linked-questions-only-works-one-way) and 
[“More linked questions” view does not show all linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126639/more-linked-questions-view-does-not-show-all-linked-questions).

Comment: Hurray! An SE developer put `status-planned` on [“More linked questions” view does not show all linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126639/224469) and wrote: *Our approach to this will be to show a more true list of the linked questions when you click the "more linked questions" link, rather than relying on the search engine.*

Comment: Hurray$^{2}$! `status-planned` has been replaced with `status-completed`. Clicking "see more linked questions" now works as one would expect: it shows all links the system knows about, either way.